# Attempt to reuse RNNCell with a different variable scope

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm using Tensorflow 1.1.0 with GPU support and I have this function:

```
def get_init_cell(batch_size, rnn_size, keep_prob=0.75, layers=2):
    """
    Create an RNN Cell and initialize it.
    :param batch_size: Size of batches
    :param rnn_size: Size of RNNs
    :return: Tuple (cell, initialize state)
    """
    # Basic LSTM cell
    # lstm = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(rnn_size)
    lstm = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(rnn_size, forget_bias=0.0, state_is_tuple=True, reuse=tf.get_variable_scope().reuse)

    # Add drop to the cell
    drop = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(lstm, output_keep_prob=keep_prob)

    # Stack multiple LSTM layers
    rnn_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([drop for _ in range(layers)], state_is_tuple=True)

    # Getting an initial state of zeros
    initial_state = rnn_cell.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32)

    # Set the name
    initial_state = tf.identity(initial_state, 'initial_state')

    return rnn_cell, initial_state
```

The previous code works perfectly with Tensorflow 1.0.0 if I use `lstm = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(rnn_size)` but now I have changed the way I get the lstm cell. And I get this error:

> ValueError: Attempt to reuse RNNCell
>    with a different variable scope than its
>   first use.  First use of cell was with scope
>   'rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/basic_lstm_cell', this attempt is with
>   scope 'rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_1/basic_lstm_cell'.  Please create a
>   new instance of the cell if you would like it to use a different set
>   of weights.  If before you were using:
>   MultiRNNCell([BasicLSTMCell(...)] * num_layers), change to:
>   MultiRNNCell([BasicLSTMCell(...) for _ in range(num_layers)]).  If
>   before you were using the same cell instance as both the forward and
>   reverse cell of a bidirectional RNN, simply create two instances (one
>   for forward, one for reverse).  In May 2017, we will start
>   transitioning this cell's behavior to use existing stored weights, if
>   any, when it is called with scope=None (which can lead to silent model
>   degradation, so this error will remain until then.)

I have changed `get_init_cell` with this one:

```
def lstm_cell(rnn_size, keep_prob=0.75):
    # Basic LSTM cell
    lstm = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(rnn_size, reuse=tf.get_variable_scope().reuse)

    # Add drop to the cell
    return tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(lstm, output_keep_prob=keep_prob)

def get_init_cell(batch_size, rnn_size, keep_prob=0.75, layers=2):
    """
    Create an RNN Cell and initialize it.
    :param batch_size: Size of batches
    :param rnn_size: Size of RNNs
    :return: Tuple (cell, initialize state)
    """    
    # Stack multiple LSTM layers
    rnn_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([lstm_cell(rnn_size, keep_prob) for _ in range(layers)])

    # Getting an initial state of zeros
    initial_state = rnn_cell.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32)

    # Set the name
    initial_state = tf.identity(initial_state, 'initial_state')

    return rnn_cell, initial_state
```

And I still getting the same error.

I have also try it with the same error:

```
def get_init_cell(batch_size, rnn_size, keep_prob=0.75, layers=2):
    """
    Create an RNN Cell and initialize it.
    :param batch_size: Size of batches
    :param rnn_size: Size of RNNs
    :return: Tuple (cell, initialize state)
    """    

    def lstm_cell():
        # Basic LSTM cell
        return tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(rnn_size, reuse=tf.get_variable_scope().reuse)        

    def attn_cell():
        return tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(lstm_cell(), output_keep_prob=keep_prob)

    # Stack multiple LSTM layers
    rnn_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([attn_cell() for _ in range(layers)], state_is_tuple=True)

    # Getting an initial state of zeros
    initial_state = rnn_cell.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32)

    # Set the name
    initial_state = tf.identity(initial_state, 'initial_state')

    return rnn_cell, initial_state
```

Any idea?

Comment: Can you give a small self-contained piece of code that reproduces the issue (i.e., a minimal script that exhibits the problem with no external dependencies, that we can run and debug?). I couldn't reproduce the issue myself based on your description. Thanks!